# Handling errors in defer

Tags: go

I have a function which open db connection and return it. Or error, if something happened:

```
OpenDbConnection(connectionString string, logSql bool) (*gorm.DB, error)
```

In this function I am using logger:

```
logger := zap.NewExample().Sugar()
defer logger.Sync()
```

Method `Sync()` returns `error` and I am ignoring this error.

What is the best strategy in this case ?

I can rewrite my code to avoid linter error, but I am still ignore error:

```
logger := zap.NewExample().Sugar()
defer func() {
    _ = logger.Sync()
}()
```

I can return error, but I am have correct db connection and I need to analyze this error in the calling function to understand what to do.

Comment: if you want to return / catch error from defer, I used named return variables. like [returning a defered error](https://pocketgophers.com/handling-errors-in-defer/#returning-a-deferred-error) , you only have to assign error variable name to error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can name your returning error variable and initialize anywhere inside the function.

check this test code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/K1k-CduETob)

```
OpenDbConnection(connectionString string, logSql bool) (db *gorm.DB, err error) {

    logger := zap.NewExample().Sugar()
    defer func() {
        err = logger.Sync()
    }()

    // some logic here

    return db, err

}
```

Comment: The flaw in this as written is that if there is an error set inside the `// some logic here` section (e.g., `if ... { err := errors.New("bad"); return nil, err; }`) you will *overwrite* it with the result of `logger.Sync`. This may result in returning *no* error, if `logger.Sync` succeeds, even though the actual open failed.

Comment: you are right. to bypass this situation we can return an array of errors `errs []error` containing both deferred and logical errors.

Comment: Or you can check the error returned by `logger.Sync()` in the defer and only overwrite the `err` variable if it's not nil.

Answer (score 5):

Another pitfall of the accepted answer with error checking like

```golang
OpenDbConnection(connectionString string, logSql bool) (db *gorm.DB, err error) {
    logger := zap.NewExample().Sugar()
    defer func() {
        errS := logger.Sync()
        if errS != nil {
           err = errS
        }
    }()

   // some logic here
```

If the `err` variable was set in the `some logic` part before the `defer` function is called. The original error could be overridden with the `logger.Sync()` error.

---

In [Go 1.20](https://go.dev/doc/go1.20#errors), the `errors.Join` was added to handling the multiple errors

> The new function `errors.Join` returns an error wrapping a list of errors.

```golang
OpenDbConnection(connectionString string, logSql bool) (db *gorm.DB, err error) {
    logger := zap.NewExample().Sugar()
    defer func() {
        err = errors.Join(err, logger.Sync())
    }()

   // some logic here
```

Now, if any of the errors occur, the `err` will be set. In the case where both errors, we get a new error where they are joined with a `\n` delimiter.